# yt-dlp installation failed "Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h'"

Tags: python

I tried to install it doing pip install yt-dlp, it started well then at the end said:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

(I'm using pycharm and yt-dl installation gone well... only yt-dlp gives me this error)

Comment: You can try installing it through pycharm and see if that works. Go to file>settings>project>python interpreter then click the + button and look up yt-dlp. Click install package. Does that produce the same error?

Comment: yes, it produces the same error, I tried also different version...